# Playing RTSP stream in VLC player

Tags: vlc, rtsp, live-streaming, rtsp-client

I am trying to make a simple rtsp streaming server in java. The server is able to stream the video properly to the custom written player.

The problem I that I am not able to play the same stream in vlc media player.
When I start the vlc media player and enter the streaming details, my server is displaying the following request made by vlc:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.2.8:8210/movie.3gp RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: VLC media player (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.01.07)
```

In response, I am sending the following to the vlc player:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Supported:  play.basic, con.persistent
CSeq: 1
Server:  Android mini RTSP Server
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE
```

After this, vlc media player is sending me a `null token` but I am expecting `DESCRIBE` or `SETUP` token.

Any idea why vlc is sending me `null token`? Is there anything I am missing in the response to the vlc's request?

Comment: Remove extra whitespace before header values

Answer (score 0):

try to keep as close as possible to the rfc.
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt

try to remove the Supported: and Server: lines.