# RTSP decribe header without response

Tags: java, android, header, rtsp, sdp

I'm writing RTSP streaming server and I need some help. I think I've tried everything and read topics:

[Receiving video stream from an IP camera on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685625/receiving-video-stream-from-an-ip-camera-on-android)

[Playing RTSP stream in VLC player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880739/playing-rtsp-stream-in-vlc-player)

[Android local RTSP server (spoof), PVPlayer closes TCP socket after DESCRIBE reply sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973065/android-local-rtsp-server-spoof-pvplayer-closes-tcp-socket-after-describe-rep)

and other similiar to them. I also read many pdfs and RFCs of course.

My story: I wrote rtsp server and problem appears when I am sending resposponse to DESCRIBE header:

```
responseHeader.append(HeaderStates.OK);
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append(CSeq);
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("session: ");
responseHeader.append(Long.valueOf(sessionID));
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
Date date = new Date();
responseHeader.append("Date: ");
responseHeader.append(date.toGMTString());
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("Content-Type: application/sdp");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("Content-Base: ");
responseHeader.append(localAddress.getHostAddress());
responseHeader.append(":");
responseHeader.append(Integer.valueOf(localPort));
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("v=0");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("o=- ");
responseHeader.append(date.getTime());
responseHeader.append(" ");
responseHeader.append(date.getTime());
responseHeader.append(" IN IP4 ");
responseHeader.append(localAddress.getHostAddress());
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("a=control:rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("s=RTSPSession");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("m=video 55555 RTP/AVP 26");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("a=rtpmap:26 JPEG/90000");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append("a=mimetype:video/JPEG");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
//responseHeader.append("a=control:trackID=1");
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
responseHeader.append(CRLF);
```

where HeaderStates.OK is "200 OK", SessionID is  System.currentTimeMillis(), CRLF = "\r\n" and responseHeader starts with "RTSP/1.0 "

then VLC (client on my PC throws unhadled exception and crashes), SMPlayer reads header and shows it in log but don't response.

Sometimes I get in SMPlayer log that says about error in SDP but I think cause of this error is too long debuging.

My question: What I've done wrong? Why there is no SETUP header from client?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the `CSeq` header in in the RtspResponse and thus it's invalid.

Also in your example you are returning a SDP so you need the `Content-Length` header!

Check out my server @ http://net7mma.codeplex.com/ to see the code of an existing implementation although it is in C# you should be able to get what you need.